# Alignment issue with ngrok deployment - Localhost tunnel

Tags: html, css, alignment, ngrok, hamburger-menu

I have deployed my project in apache tomcat. In order to make it publicly available I have used ngrok for localhost tunneling. When I run my project chrome and checked with mobile version the alignment is fine as below 
[image]

But when i view my project with the ngrok generated URL the alignment is not proper and also the font is not applied for the logo in the hamburger menu. Whats wrong ?

[image]